# Error when I try to run my code with VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, macos-monterey

I have been using VSCode for quite a while now, and I haven't had any problems until now. All of a sudden, I start getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOvjb.png) when I try to run my code (connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1:49363 - Local (127.0.0.1:49617)).

Here is my VSCode info:

```
Version: 1.71.2 (Universal)
Commit: 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7
Date: 2022-09-14T21:05:37.721Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 19.0.12
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Any suggestions on how I can get it working again. I am running MacOS 12.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. It turns out that the interface was down. To fix this, I ran:

```bash
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1 up
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but you might want to read this:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130111

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried all the solutions on the issue, and it doesn't look like VSCode will do anything about it. It was working before, I am wondering how I can get it to work as it used to.